# Why isn't this code working ? (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I'm making a code that accepts a number with only 8 or 7 digits and then if the user enters an 8 digit number then it should add all 8 digits together then divide by 10 and print out the answer. I have been trying to change the user's input into a list but it hasn't been working out.
My current code (not working):

```
NumGiven=''
while not NumGiven.isnumeric():
    NumGiven=(input('Please enter a 7 or 8 digit number:'))
while len(NumGiven)<7 or len(NumGiven)>8:
    NumGiven=(input('Please enter a 7 or 8 digit number:'))
if len(NumGiven)==8:
    list=[int(i) for i in NumGiven.split()]
```

I think there is something wrong with the last line, I looked at many other topics but they never seemed to work. Can some one help me tweak this code.

Comment: You should combine your loops

Comment: Voting to reopen.  The supposed duplicate question is about reading integers, but this one is about string splitting.

Comment: What is the behavior you observe that leads you to believe that it is not working?

Comment: @recursive thank you it's not the same thing.

Comment: your last line should be something like `print(sum([int(i) for i in NumGiven]))`

Answer (score 2):

`NumGiven.split()` splits on whitespace, but there probably isn't any.  Since you want to iterate over characters, you can just eliminate the `.split()`.

```
list=[int(i) for i in NumGiven]
```

Comment: Also, it's usually a good idea to avoid using identifiers such as `list`, since that is a python builtin. Use `the_list` or `_list` or `digits`.

Comment: thanks for your answer,so if I use the line you have given me , will it turn my string to a list meaning I can add the 8 digits together ?

Comment: @HåkenLid thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @wdwdwdw: Yes, it will give you a list.

Comment: EDIT: thanks it all works now , I appreciate your help.

Comment: You could show your appreciation by selecting recursive's answer as the correct one!

Answer (score 0):

OP asked for the sum - it should be:

```
 print(sum([int(i) for i in NumGiven])/10.0)
```

Comment: you forgot to divide by 10.

Comment: @domo Thanks , I know how to do it , it was just turning the string into a list , but thanks.

Comment: Thanks you very much guys xD